# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'find' of undefined for react-redux

Tags: python, django, react-redux

Please help me fix this error : Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'find' of undefined.

All code as below ;

```
import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from '../constants/cartConstants'


export const cartReducer = (state = {cartItems: []}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CART_ADD_ITEM:
            const item = action.payload
            const existItem = state.cartItems.find(x => x.product === item.product)

        if (existItem) {
            return {
                ...state,
                cartItems: state.cartItems.map(x =>
                    x.product === existItem.product ? item : x)
            }

        } else {
            return {
                ...state,
                cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item]
            }
        }

    default:
        return state
}
```

}

this is CartAction

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from '../constants/cartConstants'


export const addToCart = (id, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)

    dispatch({
        type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
        payload: {
            product: data._id,
            name: data.name,
            image: data.image,
            price: data.price,
            countInStock: data.countInStock,
            qty
        }
    })

    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import { listProducts, listProductDetails } from './reducers/productReducers'
import { cartReducer } from './reducers/cartReducers'


const cartFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartITems') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems')) : []

**const initialState = {
```

cart: { *cartITems:* cartFromLocalStorage }
}**

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
    productsList: listProducts,
    productDetails: listProductDetails,
    cart: cartReducer,
})

const middleware = [thunk]

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
)

export default store
```

if found the same error while I was giving "cartFromLocalStorage" in the initialState, and I made mistake in declaring `cart: { cartITems: cartFromLocalStorage }`instead of `cart: { cartItems: cartFromLocalStorage }`, i used Capital T in cartItems, so i corrected it, now add to cart is working fine [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/so1NX.png)